# Creating a Hypothetical Hexagonal Monolayer Structure Similar to MoS2

Tags: density-functional-theory, vasp, molecular-modeling, visualization-software

I am seeking guidance on how to generate a POSCAR file for a hypothetical monolayer with a hexagonal structure similar to MoS2. Can anyone provide me with a step-by-step procedure or recommend any software or tools that can assist me in this process? Any help or advice would be greatly appreciated.
Thank you.

Comment: +1 Welcome to our forum!

Answer (score 3):

I strongly advise using online databases/projects to obtain the CIF/POSCAR files.

One that I recommend is [The Material Project](https://next-gen.materialsproject.org/):

[image]

Here, you can search for materials information by chemistry, composition, or property:

[image]

At the left menu, there is the option "Crystal Toolkit", where you can cut the crystal informing the Miller indexes.

[image]
[image]

Also, you can download the CIF for the crystal, and then use programs like [CIF2Cell](https://sourceforge.net/projects/cif2cell/) to cut the crystal and create the desired supercell.

Comment: I understand that OP is asking for how to build a hypothetical structure, thus I think he/she needs the procedure on how to read and adjust a CIF file that could be obtained from the database you have mentioned, or how to create one from scratch.

Comment: yes i want to create a structure of a RhBr2 similar to MoS2.but its cif and POSCAR is not available

Comment: After downloading de CIF/POSCAR and create the slab, creating the hypothetical structure is straight forward: open the files in any text editor and change the atom labels.

Comment: @FarahShehzadi, I am not sure what you mean by its similar to MoS2, do you mean it has the same space group? Anyhow, RhBr2 crystal structure can be found from other databases if you don't want to bother making your own file, check the following https://oqmd.org/materials/composition/RhBr2, at the end of this page you will find a list of the compounds with different space groups, check whether it has the one you are looking for. If you don't have access to that link then let me know.

Comment: Yes I aim to recreate a crystal structure with a hexagonal lattice and the same space group as MoS2.

Comment: @Camps  While I understand the basic process of opening CIF or POSCAR files in a text editor to change atom labels, I am aware that directly altering these files may not be sufficient, especially when it comes to adjusting lattice parameters.
My concern lies in ensuring that the modified crystal structure retains the desired hexagonal lattice and the same space group as the original material.

Comment: @JaafarMehrez thank you,requesting assistance in obtaining crystal structure data for a Space Group P6̅m2 structure was not found in the provided link.

Comment: @FarahShehzadi, in this case you could follow the suggestion by Camps, search for a CIF/POSCAR file that has the same space group and composition to the one you are looking for and adjust the atomic species in that file with any text editor.

Comment: @JaafarMehrez ok thank you, While I understand the basic process of opening CIF or POSCAR files in a text editor to change atom labels, I am aware that directly altering these files may not be sufficient, especially when it comes to adjusting lattice parameters. My concern lies in ensuring that the modified crystal structure retains the desired hexagonal lattice and the same space group as the original material.

Comment: @JaafarMehrez How can I estimate the lattice parameters when creating a new crystal structure for a monolayer with space groupP6̅m2?

Comment: @FarahShehzadi, We would better move this discussion to chat

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/151616/discussion-between-jaafar-mehrez-and-farah-shehzadi).